# Dropzone.js with mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, dropzone.js

I want insert in Mysql the files of Dropzone.js form.

How can make this?

HTML CODE

```
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone"></form>
```

PHP UPLOAD CODE

```
<?php
$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1

$storeFolder = 'uploads';   //2

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             

    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4

    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6

}
?>
```

Comment: So whats wrong with you code? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I want insert in this code a mysql instructions for save in database the files upload. This code work ok.

Comment: You still need to give more details - what do you want to save? the filepath? The actual image (mySql Blob)? the time and date of upload? Also, what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this below

```
<?php   
require 'functions/myconnectionfile.php';

$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$storeFolder = "uploads/";

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $fileupload = basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $fileupload;
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    $uploadsql = "INSERT INTO uploads (Filename, description, Type, Size)
                  VALUES ('$fileupload', 'test uploads', '$fileType', '$fileSize')";
    mysql_query($uploadsql);
}
?>
```